# How to move UIButtons?

Tags: ios, uibutton, swift2

How to move the button when pressed?

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) { 
    if let touch = touches.first { 
        location = touch.locationInView(self.view)
        Button.center = location 
    } 
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent:event) 
} 
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) { 
    if let touch = touches.first { 
        location = touch.locationInView(self.view) 
        Button.center = location 
    } 
    super.touchesMoved(touches, withEvent:event)
}
```

The button does not move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're placing your buttons using AutoLayout, then you have to update the constraints that determine the button positions.

This is usually done by exposing the constraint to your view as an `IBOutlet` and modifying its `constant` property (which isn't actually constant at all).

You would need two constraints:

- horizontal distance from the left of your `UIView`
- vertical distance from top the top of your `UIView`

e.g.

```
horizontalConstraint.constant = location.x
verticalConstraint.constant = location.y
```

If you're not using AutoLayout (i.e. you're using autoresizing/springs and struts) then your above code should just work. So you could try turning AutoLayout off in your view's xib.